# Custom autoload conflicts with Composer's autoload?

Tags: php, composer-php, phpunit, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I have a PHP project that loads a bootstrap file called `custom_funcs.php`, which is located in the root web directory. This file contains a pile of functions, defines several Constants, and does the following:

```
    require dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/lib/php/vendor/autoload.php';
    spl_autoload_register( function ($class_name) { include __DIR__ ."/classes/$class_name.php"; });
    set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . SITEROOT );
```

That first line loads the Composer autoloader. (Note the composer libraries are located outside the root web directory). The second line tells my code where to look for unrecognized Classes so I don't have to constantly manual-load ever Class file I ever use.  The third line adds the web root to PHP's PATH.

This has been working just fine, along with several Composer packages, for a couple years now.

Then... I installed PhpUnit.  Overall I have it working alright, except when I run tests:

1. If there are no errors, it works normally.
2. If there is an error, I also get PHP warnings:

```
Warning: include(C:\...path_to_web_root.../classes/SebastianBergmann\Invoker\Invoker.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\...path_to_web_root...\common_funcs.php on line 14
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\...path_to_web_root.../classes/SebastianBergmann\Invoker\Invoker.php' for inclusion (include_path='xxxxxxx') in C:\...path_to_web_root...\common_funcs.php on line 14
```

So PhpUnit is trying to autoload a class called "Invoker", but the code is using my own autoload path set by `spl_autoload_register`.

Is there a way to fix this?  Is this a bug in PhpUnit?

I can hide the error by using "@" before the include line, but I try to avoid @hiding errors at all costs

Note: I'm loading `custom_funcs.php` before testing via:

```
    public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void {
        require 'common_funcs.php';
    }
```

The file structure might make it more clear:

```
c:/some_path/
..lib/
....php/
......vendor/
........(third-party Composer libraries)
..webroot/
....custom_funcs.php
....classes/
......(namespace)/
........(my custom classes)
```

I am using a namespace: `MyCompany\Portal`.  So my custom classes are found in `<webroot>/classes/MyCompany/Portal/`

Comment: Make your custom_func a class and add it to PSR4 autoloader. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: That sounds a lot like "rewrite your enter codebase". With a few notable (and recent) exceptions, this is a legacy system that is entirely procedural.  The `custom_funcs.php` is nothing that would make a cohesive sensible Object class -- it's a bunch of reusable functions that I use throughout the site.

Comment: "The second line tells my code where to look for unrecognized Classes so I don't have to constantly manual-load ever Class file I ever use." thats exactly what composer is for. I dont fully understand the issue here? Add your own classes to the composer autoloader and remove that line.

Comment: If there is a way to replace my spl_autoload_register call with the Composer autoloader, I'm open to that idea, but understand the Composer and custom classes are in two different places.  Or do you mean I should take my custom classes and stick them in Composer's vendor folder?

Comment: Are you using namespaces in your own class files? If yes, you can teach composer where to find these namespaces. (See link from my first comment) They can sit whereever they want (as long as they are readable).

Comment: namespace clarification added to bottom of OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to replace your custom autoloader function with a [`classmap` autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) in your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["classes/"],
        "files": ["custom_funcs.php"]
    }
}
```

> This map is built by scanning for classes in all `.php` and `.inc` files in the given directories/files.

Whenever you create a new class, you might have to update composer's autoloader by using `composer dump-autoload` for it to be picked up. I am not sure if this is the case by default or only when optimizing the autoloader, though. In any case this could be solved by adopting PSR-0 or PSR-4 naming conventions for new classes.

edit: Since all files will be autoloaded for you with composer's autoloader, it should not be necessary anymore to `require` them manually. Therefore you could also remove the `setupBeforeClass`-method

Comment: I've tried this, but I need to know what the "classmap" and "files" paths are relative to.  Site root? `composer.json`?  `phpunit.xml`?  The directory with the `phpunit` executable?  Couldn't get it to work, and every example I can find online seems to assume a very specific directory structure

Comment: Note: I can't remove the `setupBeforeClass` method, because that loads the file with the functions I'm testing in the first place.  But I *would* be able to remove the manual class-caller from that file (`common_funcs.php`).

Comment: The paths should be relative to your `composer.json`, which in most cases is the same as the project root (not site root). So it might be that you have to do `webroot/classes` instead of classes. You can perform `composer dump-autoload -vvv` which will give you a verbose output which classes it collected.

Comment: The `dump-autoload` was the clincher. Everything seems to be working now. I was able to remove the manual `spl_autoload_register`; though I left the common_funcs file because that has my standard functions. Thanks

Comment: Note that you will need to run `composer dump-autoload` every time when you rename or add new class. Using `classmap` may be fine for stale codebase, but if this is live thing you should rather use [`psr-4`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) instead.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to fix your autoloader - autoloader should not throw such errors if he is not able to load class. Doing nothing is correct action in this case:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    if (file_exists(__DIR__ . "/classes/$class_name.php")) {
        include __DIR__ . "/classes/$class_name.php";
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: An elegant, straightforward workaround, but I went with the one that properly gets things working

Comment: @StephenR This is not an workaround, this is how you should implement your own autoloader in this case. Although using composer autoloader may be simpler and more efficient solution, there may be cases when you may need custom implementation and you can't use autoloader from composer.

Comment: Good point.  I've actually implemented both suggestions, so thanks.

Comment: @rob006 nice! How about:

`if (is_readable(__DIR__ . "/classes/$class_name.php"))`

?